# VB.NET System.IndexOutOfRangeException in checkbox

Tags: vb.net, forms, indexoutofrangeexception

I am studying form event for VB.NET

My program is loading and setting some of date on the VB.NET form.

I suddenly get System.IndexOutOfRangeException when software switch check box to true

for example, I am using control and for loop to switch check box status
I am using control method to looping and searching checkbox in the groupbox

```
For Each c As Control In GT.SET_MY.Controls
    If c.GetType Is GetType(CheckBox) Then
        Dim sc As CheckBox = DirectCast(c, CheckBox)
        If BW_List(BW_INDEX).Trim = "Y" Then
            **sc.Checked = CB.T** ' **ERR POINT**
            Tracker = sc.Text
        Else
            sc.Checked = CB.F
        End If
        BW_INDEX -= 1
    End If
Next
```

When program is set checkbox to false like  " sc.Checked = CB.F". It doesn't have any error

However, when program is set checkbox to true(sc.Checked = CB.T), it returns to System.IndexOutOfRangeException

I am not clearly sure why this happen...

error message is

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in Myproject.exe
>
> Step into: Stepping over non-user code
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow'
>
> Step into: Stepping over non-user code
>   'System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback'
>
> Step into: Stepping over non-user code
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore'
>
> Step into: Stepping over non-user code
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore'

does anybody know why this happen ?

OK

I found major problem of this error

When Software is automatically check or uncheck, it randomly triggers some events in the software and it become cause of error.

Comment: What is CB? What are the values of CB.F & CB.T?

Comment: @  User999999 thanks for your helping CB.F and CB.T is checking or un checking checkbox

Comment: BW_List(BW_INDEX) is a very dangerous expression.  The *next* checkbox will trigger this exception since -1 is not a valid index.

Comment: @ Hans Passant  oh you are right!!! I already fixed the problems, but it can be cause of another problem. i will change it right now. Thanks for your help :)